# Windows 10, MAMP virtual host setup doesn't work

Tags: apache, mamp, virtualhost

I've went through all the posts I could find here, still couldn't get this to work:

I Have a Windows 10 + MAMP.

MAMP is set to folder C:/MAMP/htdocs as the root folder

I un-commented the Virtual host line on the httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Added :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/MAMP/htdocs/team/example"
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAlias dev.examplecom
</VirtualHost>
```

into httpds-vhosts.conf to the extra folder (under conf)

added the following to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.example.com
```

I Can get to localhost,
But every time I try a domain, it gices me: Not Found (The requested URL / was not found on this server.)

I'm pretty sure I am missing something small, But will greatly appreciate a solution to this.

So far i tried changing the Path in the conf files.
Tried  using relative paths rather than absolute.
Tried any idea I could find onlie,

Thanks, and a happy new year :)
Cheers.

Comment: I've just did what you said and it worked. did you restart the apache ? you tabbed in your hosts file. dont use space, just [ip] tab [domain]

Comment: I had exactly the same problem. Consider that the virtual hosts need to be correctly enabled/included by uncommenting
"Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" in C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf and NOT in C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf or C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\original .

Comment: I have found that MAMP is a bit odd here. Your Virtual Hosts directive goes into `C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf`. However, the actual `httpd-vhosts.conf` file is located at `C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf`, that is, in the `bin` directory. Not sure why, but this is how I got it working.

Answer (score 4):

Changing the line from `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to `Include C:/MAMP/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` worked for me.

It seems that `httpd.conf` requires absolute paths

Comment: No, `httpd.conf` is fine with relative paths. I have found, however, that MAMP behaves a little oddly as to where it looks.

Comment: Mamp seems to require the absolute path. It's weird.

Comment: Include C:\MAMP\bin\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I didn't see you mention anything about SymLink, maybe that's what you're missing to make it work.

Find this line in that same `C:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf` file.

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride none
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change `AllowOverride` from **none** to **all**

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Although I'm late to the party, hope that helps.

Also make sure to restart the servers on MAMP after making any changes! If you don't reset the server to apply the changes, nothing will work even though you know you've done everything right.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this question is still relevant but I was having the exact same problem setting up my Virtual Host recently and I was receiving the: **Not Found (The requested URL / was not found on this server.)**. The solution for me was to write it as the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot C:/MAMP/htdocs/team/example
    ServerName dev.example.com
    ServerAlias dev.examplecom
</VirtualHost>
```

Without the quotations around the DocumentRoot. Seems both simple and dumb but it worked for me. Make sure to restart the Mamp Servers again!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment on James's answer, but this is another quirk of the Windows environment:

In the hosts file, Windows wants two lines for each virtual host:

```
127.0.0.1     dev.example.com
::1           dev.example.com
```